# trouble with if statement going to button and div

Tags: javascript, function, html, if-statement

I'm trying to get my function to look at a number entered into a text box, and if it's larger than x number (I put in 5 for example purposes) display one message in theDiv, if less than or equal to, another. Right now I click the button and nothing happens. I'm trying to learn Javascript for the first time, so forgive my ignorance - where did I go wrong? Thank you!!

```
<script>
function function1()
{
for (var theNumber)
{
var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value);

if (theNumber < 5)
    {
    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML="Smaller.";
    }

else (theNumber >= 5)
    {
    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML="Larger.";
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="function1()"></p>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value);
```

to

```
var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theButton').value);
```

and dont use any condition in `else, else` do not take any condition, rather than that you can use `else if`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you are missing a closing curly bracket.
2. And then your `else` part should not have any conditions.
3. Your `for` syntax is wrong and you dont need it here.
4. Last but not the least, you are getting the value of `theInput`, that is not there in the form at all.

So your modified code looks like this

```
function function1() {
    var theNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value);
    if (theNumber < 5) {
        document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = "Smaller.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = "Larger.";
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/V3QBc/

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems present here.

1.) You do **not** have a DOM element with an `id="theInput"`

2.) You are mis-using the `for` construct, which is for looping. The correct syntax is `for (incrementer_variable; condition_to_continue_looping; increment_by) {}`

3.) You are specifying an `else if` condition using only `else` (meaning your condition will be ignored.

4.) You are missing a closing curly brace (`}`) to finish defining `function1`.

To fix these, add a DOM element with `id="theInput"`, remove the `for` (it's not needed here), add that last curly brace, and either add an `if` after the `else` or remove the condition (depending on the behavior you want).

```
<input type="text" id="theInput">
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="function1()">
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function function1() {
var theNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value, 10);
if (theNumber < 5) {
    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = "Smaller.";
} else if (theNumber >= 5) {
    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = "Larger.";
}
```

}
Another minor problem (in potentia) is that you are not specifying a radix for `parseFloat`. This can cause problems if the JavaScript engine thinks your number has a different base than 10. To ensure you always get a base10 number, specify a radix for the second argument to `parseFloat`: (`var x = parseFloat(otherVar, 10);`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8tS7t/